# Consecutive edges on Eulerian Circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

Given an Eulerian graph G and 2 edges adjacent on the same vertex. Is there an Eulerian circuit that these two edges are consecutive? ie e1 - V1 - e2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The previous version of this answer was incorrect as it did not consider all cases. Thanks to @D.L for pointing this out in comments)

**Equivalent Question:** $\forall$ eulerian graph $G$ and given any two edges $\{e_1,e_2\}$ adjacent to a vertex V, can we construct an eulerian path $P$ going through $\{e_1,e_2\}$ consecutively?

**Answer:** No, we cannot construct such a path. Please see here: [If $G$ is an Eulerian graph with edges $a$, $b$ sharing a vertex $v$, is it true that $G$ has an Eulerian trail in which $a$, $b$ are consecutive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109883/if-g-is-an-eulerian-graph-with-edges-a-b-sharing-a-vertex-v-is-it-true)

Comment: I have a question. Why is it true that if there is a single cycle then $e_1$ and $e_2$ are consecutive? I was considering the union of two triangles with one common vertex (which looks like a figure-eight). Say $v_1$ is the common vertex and $e_1$ and $e_2$ are edges in one triangle. How can we find an Eulerian circuit with consecutive $e_1$ and $e_2$ in this case?

Comment: Right, there is a case where one cannot an eulerian circuit with two edges adjacent. There are 3 cases - 
(Case 1). There is a single cycle in the graph. In this case, There are just 2 edges passing through any vertex, and hence they are adjacent. 
(Case 2). There are multiple cycles, but the edges considered belong to different cycles. Here too we can find an eulerian cycle.
(Case 3). Both edges belong to same cycle and there are multiple cycles: Here, we cannot find a cycle with the edges adjacent as you point out.
I had incorrectly considered only cases 1 and 2. Thanks for pointing out.