# Are the following two properties of Eulerian graphs true?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, eulerian-path

Can someone help to verify the following two properties, perhaps by indicating what properties of eulerian graphs is used in them?

Q1: Let $G$ be a connected graph containing a Eulerian circuit. If $G$ is bipartite then it has an even number of edges.

Q2: Let $G$ be as in Q1. For edges $e$ and $f$ sharing a vertex, $G$ has an Euler circuit in
which $e$ and $f$ appear consecutively.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but I think my graph theory is a bit rusty. Is tour the same thing as a path or a cycle? Also, what have your tried already in regards to this problem?

Comment: Apologies if that was unclear terminology. I have tour to mean cycle.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, consider the partition of the vertices of the graph $G$ into $S_1$ and $S_2$. Let the circuit in question start in $S_1$. No edges $e = (v_i,v_j)$ exist where $v_i$ and $v_j$ are both in $S_1$ or $S_2$.

A Eulerian circuit cannot go from a member of $S_1$ to another member of $S_1$, as no such edges exist, so it must alternate between $S_1$ and $S_2$. As a result, if we label the n-th edge $e_n$, for even $n$, it will land in $S_1$, and for odd $n$ it will land in $S_2$.

However, it is also a circuit, and so it must return to $S_1$, meaning that the final edge will have an even index, also showing that the total number of edges is even.

For Q2, it is not necessarily true. Consider the following graph:

[image]

It is not possible to traverse the sequence $BAC$ without cutting off the vertices $E$ and $D$. Also answered here: [If $G$ is an Eulerian graph with edges $a$, $b$ sharing a vertex $v$, is it true that $G$ has an Eulerian trail in which $a$, $b$ are consecutive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109883/if-g-is-an-eulerian-graph-with-edges-a-b-sharing-a-vertex-v-is-it-true)

Comment: The image of the graph didn't load

Comment: Reloaded it, does it work now?

Comment: Afraid not, although I think the post you linked has helped me make sense of the argument. Thanks!